# Sorting ArrayAdapter for Android

Tags: android, sorting, drop-down-menu, android-arrayadapter

I have a MultiAutoCompleteTextView which lets you enter in multiple entries and shows you autocomplete suggestions. My issue arises when I submit my data. I am adding any entered strings to the drop down list, but my attempts to sort the data fail. The code that executes on submit:

```
final private Comparator<String> comp = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String e1, String e2) {
        return e1.toString().compareTo(e2.toString());
    }
};

((ArrayAdapter<String>) autoCompleteView.getAdapter()).add(getString());                    
((ArrayAdapter<String>) autoCompleteView.getAdapter()).sort(comp);
```

The code for what happens on clicking the autoCompleteView:

```
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(null);
                //adapter.sort(comp);
                view.showDropDown();
            }
        });
```

Can anyone find anything wrong with what I'm doing?

EDIT: some more info, after incorporating changes from @Sam

```
private ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        array);

private void setUpAutoComplete(final MultiAutoCompleteTextView view)
{
    array.add("test string");   // this is successfully added to the drop down list
    Collections.sort(array, comp);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void onSubmit()
{
    array.add(getString()); // this fails to add
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> but my attempts to sort the data fail

This is a little vague. But I'll take a guess.

First you do something redundant:

```
return e1.toString().compareTo(e2.toString());
```

Since `e1` and `e2` are already Strings you don't need to call `String#toString()`. Also this basic String comparator already exists. So you don't need any of this.

A better technique is to sort the List, not the adapter. Simply use Collections' sorting method:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(getString());
...

Collections.sort(list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Notice I changed `adapter.add()` to `list.add()`. I did this because `adapter.add()` calls `list.add()` *and* `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but the adapter shouldn't be updated until *after* the new list is sorted.

Comment: Thanks. I've added this code into the part that executes when I submit, but the drop down list doesn't update at all with the new entry. When I add the code into the part where the adapter is initialized however, the added string is successfully added.Does this sound like an issue with (threads) not being able to modify existing data?

Comment: I don't see where you are using threads or the overall context, so I cannot be certain...

Comment: getString() just does view.getText(); I've tried hard-coding it as well, with the same result.

Comment: Have you verified that onSubmit() is called?

Comment: Yes. When putting a breakpoint at array.add(getString()), I can see that array now contains the string. But I'm not sure how that reflects on the adapter. Attempting to type a string matching the added string e.g. "test string" after hitting submit will not bring up "test string" as an autocomplete suggestion, and "test string" isn't brought up in the drop down if I simply click the view either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14025/discussion-between-sam-and-justin)

Comment: Thanks @Sam. Turns out I just had to recreate the adapter and reassign it to the view after updating the array using your solution.